# Incompatible color definition when using tikz with color package

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, incompatibility

I am using the **tikz** package to draw some diagrams. In addition, I need the color package for some highlighting. As the [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#The_68_standard_colors_known_to_dvips) page of the color package states, it has to be used *before* the tikz package. I did this and am now ending up with a huge amount of

> Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on line xxx

Where xxx stand for many many lines, I don't control.

Any ideas of fixing this?

A working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{constraints} {
    keywords = {undefined, terminate, peephole\-constraint, temporal\-constraint, condition, rationale, result, filter, sequence, link, isParent, contains, distance, state, startsWith},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    sensitive=false,
    alsodigit={-},
    ndkeywords={FAIL, FAIL_FINAL, PASS, PASS_FINAL, source, origin, sourceType, originType, operation, parameters},
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{OliveGreen},
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}

\begin{document}
Text above.\\

\begin{lstlisting}[language=constraints]
temporal-constraint observe-value {
  rationale {
  }
  sequence {
    a << b << terminate
  }
  filter a {
    operation == 'observe'
  }
  filter b {
    operation == 'value'
    &&  parameters.value != undefined
  }
  link {
      a.parameters.name == b.parameters.name
    &&  isParent(a.origin, b.origin)
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There you go, hope this helps!

Comment: I don't see any difference between using `color` or `xcolor` except no warnings with `xcolor`.

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much. xcolor fixed it...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Changing this tiny line of code

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
```

to

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

fixed it, thanks @Ignasi

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this helped, what exactly the warning means and why it is something that should be fixed :)

Comment: I am having `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.` error

Comment: Are you loading the package twice? Maybe once in the style file and once in the preamble for example.