# How can the go to summary be fixed so the \section[Some]{Some more} does not throw all these errors?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, errors, hyperref, abnt

On the question [How to automatically put a [Go To Summary] | [Go Back] on each section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367859/how-to-automatically-put-a-go-to-summary-go-back-on-each-section) I learned how to create a `go to summary` on each section on the text. However now I am having a errors when I change this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{abntex2}
```

To this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside,chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE]{abntex2}
```

Also the errors are fixed when I remove the `go to summary` section command.

This is an example with errors, i.e., using `chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside,chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE]{abntex2}

% Incompatible color definition when using tikz with color package
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150369/incompatible-color-definition-when-using-tikz-with-color-package
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{26,13,178}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkgreen}

% How to automatically put a [Go To Summary] | [Go Back] on each section?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367859/how-to-automatically-put-a-go-to-summary-go-back-on-each-section
\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,32,96}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\goToSummaryText}
{
    \hyperlink{summary} {\textcolor{ultramarine}{\small\mdseries [Go To Top]}}
    {\small\mdseries |}
    \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{\small\mdseries [Go Back]}}
}
\newcommand{\addGoToSummary}{\renewcommand{\Sectionformat}[2]{##1 \goToSummaryText}}
\newcommand{\removeGoToSummary}{\renewcommand{\Sectionformat}[2]{##1}}

\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}
{
    % Insert internal document link
    \hypertarget{summary}
    \oldtableofcontents
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\addGoToSummary

\chapter[Nullam]{Nullam elementum}
Nullam elementum

\section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}
\end{document}
```

Just by running this simple example only with one command `\section` I got several errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a 
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Use of \hyper@link@ doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@phantomsection 

l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token 
                                                  {\the \toks@ }\GTS@Predefi...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@TestLeft #1#2->\def \GTS@temp 
                                   {#1}\ifx \GTS@temp \GTS@Token \toks@ \exp...
l.41 \section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Running the example above removing the `chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE` correctly generates the document as follows:

[image]
[image]

How can the `go to summary` be fixed so the `chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE` does not throw all these errors?

---

## Update

<s>I failed to create a minimal example before posting this question. Now I am going to dig on my main document to find out how to reproduce the problem correctly.</s>

I already fixed the question with the real error/problem.

Comment: Why do you want a `\showfont` in a section heading?

Comment: For anything in special. But would be welcome to not have a command use limitation on my sections headers, as introduced by the `go to summary` feature.

Comment: I agree with @TeXnician, but your missing effectively the `\makeatother` **after** the `\showfont` definition, remove the 'intermediate' one **before** `\showfont`, the first one causes `jumping out` of the `@` catcode regime

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer, this this the problem on my example. But on my main document is giving other errors other than this. I failed to create a minimal example of the problem. I need to go back to my main document do look what is missing.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I already fixed the question/minimal example. Now the error is cause by the `chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE`.

Comment: @user: I've to fight through your setup. You redefine `\tableofcontents` but use `\tableofcontents`, so the `\hypertarget{summary}` is never set yet

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, sorry for the mess. It redefines the `tableofcontents` to add a link to it. But I use the `\tableofcontents*` on my document. The document is compilling if I remove the `chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE`.

Comment: @user: I meant `\tableofcontents*` above -- a typo

Comment: Your code has `showfont` but the error has `\showfont` at that place. (Not the error, but the context.) Is that error produced from the code you posted ***exactly***?

Comment: Off-topic: your commands are probably introducing spurious spaces. At least, if they aren't, that is going to be down to the good wishes of Lady Luck and not a result of any care on your part in coding them.

Comment: @cfr, I had copied the log from an old version of the minimal example. I just copied the current minimal example and generated a new log which is updated on the main post. The code is pretty simple, the errors are because there are some spaces on the code?

Comment: I said it was off-topic. No. the spaces aren't responsible for this problem (that I know of), but you may not want to be inserting spaces when you use these commands. Why do you need font commands in the argument of `\hyperlink`?

Comment: @cfr, I do not understand exactly what font commands you noticed. The only one I think I am using are the `\small\mdseries` and `\textcolor{ultramarine}`. But I added those to make the document more beauty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside,chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE]{abntex2}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150369/incompatible-color-definition-when-using-tikz-with-color-package
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{26,13,178}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkgreen}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367859/how-to-automatically-put-a-go-to-summary-go-back-on-each-section
\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,32,96}
\newcommand{\goToSummaryText}
{%
  \small\mdseries%
  \hyperlink{summary} { \textcolor{ultramarine}{[Go To Top]}}%
  |%
  \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{ \textcolor{ultramarine}{[Go Back]}}%
}
\newcommand{\addGoToSummary}{\renewcommand{\Sectionformat}[2]{##1 \protect\goToSummaryText}}
\newcommand{\removeGoToSummary}{\renewcommand{\Sectionformat}[2]{##1}}
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}
{%
    \hypertarget{summary}%
    \oldtableofcontents
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\addGoToSummary
\chapter[Nullam]{Nullam elementum}
Nullam elementum
\section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}
\end{document}
```

I don't know where all the arrows come into it, but I don't see them.

Comment: Thanks! It is fixed. I compared your code with mime, you added `\protect` before `\goToSummaryText` on the command `\addGoToSummary`  [changes image](http://i.imgur.com/pxhYSmm.png). You also fixed inconsistencies I had on defining `\small\mdseries` multiple times, instead of only one as you did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my minimal example fixed with [@cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222) help on the other answer, but replacing the text `[Go To Top]` and `[Go Back]` with arrows `$\leftleftarrows$` and `$\leftarrow$` respectively:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside,chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE]{abntex2}

% Incompatible color definition when using tikz with color package
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150369/incompatible-color-definition
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{26,13,178}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkgreen}

% How to automatically put a [Go To Summary] on each section?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367859/how-to-automatically-put-a-go-to
\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,32,96}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}

% The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List
% http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf
\RequirePackage{MnSymbol}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\goToSummaryText}{{%
    \small\mdseries
    \hyperlink{summary}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{$\leftleftarrows$}}
    {$|$}
    \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{$\leftarrow$}}
}}
\makeatletter
    \newif\ifismemoirloaded\ismemoirloadedfalse
    \newif\ifisabntexloaded\isabntexloadedfalse
    \@ifclassloaded{memoir}{%
        \ismemoirloadedtrue%
    }{}
    \@ifclassloaded{abntex2}{%
        \isabntexloadedtrue%
    }{}
    \newcommand{\addGoToSummary}
    {%
        \@ifundefined{printparttitle}{\message{printparttitle patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
                    be applied because there is no printparttitle command available!^^J}}{%
            \let\oldAddGoToprintparttitle\printparttitle
            \xapptocmd{\printparttitle}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
        }
        \@ifundefined{Sectionformat}{\message{Sectionformat patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
                    be applied because there is no Sectionformat command available!^^J}}{%
            \let\oldAddGoToSectionformat\Sectionformat
            \xapptocmd{\Sectionformat}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
        }
        \ifismemoirloaded
            \ifisabntexloaded
                \let\oldAddGoToABNTEXchapterupperifneeded\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded
                \xapptocmd{\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
            \else
                \let\oldAddGoToprintchaptertitle\printchaptertitle
                \xapptocmd{\printchaptertitle}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
            \fi
        \else
            \@ifundefined{Chapterformat}{\message{Chapterformat patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
                        be applied because there is no Chapterformat command available!^^J}}{%
                \let\oldAddGoToChapterformat\Chapterformat
                \xapptocmd{\Chapterformat}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
            }
        \fi
    }
    \newcommand{\removeGoToSummary}
    {%
        \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToprintparttitle}{}{\let\printparttitle\oldAddGoToprintparttitle}
        \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToSectionformat}{}{\let\Sectionformat\oldAddGoToSectionformat}
        \ifismemoirloaded
            \ifisabntexloaded
                \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToABNTEXchapterupperifneeded}{}{\let\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded\oldAddGoToABNTEXchapterupperifneeded}
            \else
                \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToprintchaptertitle}{}{\let\printchaptertitle\oldAddGoToprintchaptertitle}
            \fi
        \else
            \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToChapterformat}{}{\let\Chapterformat\oldAddGoToChapterformat}
        \fi
    }
\makeatother
\let\oldAddGoTotableofcontents\tableofcontents
% Insert internal document link
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \hypertarget{summary}%
    \oldAddGoTotableofcontents%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\addGoToSummary

\chapter[Nullam]{Nullam elementum}
Nullam elementum

\section[Some encoding tests]{showfont}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

---

Related questions to the `\protect` fix used:

1. [Minimal \protected@edef example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/minimal-protectededef-example)
2. [What is the purpose of \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12698/what-is-the-purpose-of-protect)
3. [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

Related questions:

1. [Why abntex2 class is inserting a new line after the chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485834/why-abntex2-class-is-inserting-a-new-line-after-the-chapter-title)
2. [How to automatically put a [Go To Summary] | [Go Back] on each section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367859/how-to-automatically-put-a-go-to-summary-go-back-on-each-section)
3. [How can the go to summary be fixed so the \section[Some]{Some more} does not throw all these errors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388045/how-can-the-go-to-summary-be-fixed-so-the-sectionsomesome-more)
4. [What is the equivalent to `\Sectionformat` on memoir class for `\Chapterformat`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399635/what-is-the-equivalent-to-sectionformat-on-memoir-class-for-chapterformat)
5. [Why xapptocmd is reducing the vertical space between \partname and \parttile?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485857/why-xapptocmd-is-reducing-the-vertical-space-between-partname-and-parttile)