# What is the equivalent to `\Sectionformat` on memoir class for `\Chapterformat`?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, memoir

I tried following the same as in [How to automatically put a [Go To Summary] | [Go Back] on each section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367859/how-to-automatically-put-a-go-to-summary-go-back-on-each-section):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % fix utf8 encoding problems
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % updated times new roman font

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{link_color}{RGB}{26,13,178}
\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,32,96}

\usepackage[backref,colorlinks,linkcolor=link_color]{hyperref}


\newcommand{\goToSummaryText}
{
    \small\mdseries
    \hyperlink{summary} {\textcolor{ultramarine}{{ } [Go To Top]}}
    {{ }|}
    \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{{ } [Go Back]}}
}

% How can the go to summary be fixed so does not throw all these errors?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388045/how-can-the-go-to-summary-be-fixed
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\addGoToSummary}
    {%
        \renewcommand{\Sectionformat}[2]{##1 \protect\goToSummaryText}
        \renewcommand{\Chapterformat}[2]{##1 \protect\goToSummaryText}
    }
    \newcommand{\removeGoToSummary}
    {
        \renewcommand{\Sectionformat}[2]{##1}
        \renewcommand{\Chapterformat}[2]{##1}
    }
\makeatother

\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}
{
    % Insert internal document link
    \hypertarget{summary}
    \oldtableofcontents
}

\begin{document}

\addGoToSummary
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\section{Section One Four}

\end{document}
```

But it stopped working completely:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It should be something like this bellow, I mounted it with paint. I am not sure how exactly it could be, but should follow something like is fine:

[image]
[image]

---

## Update

I had forgot to call `\addGoToSummary`, now I fixed the main code but now I got the error:

```
test2.tex:48: LaTeX Error: \Chapterformat undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
TeX STOPPED: fatal errors occurred. Check the TeX log file for details
```

The question is actually what is the equivalent to `\Sectionformat` on memoir class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the command is `\printchaptertitle`:

```latex
\makeatletter
    \newif\ifismemoirloaded\ismemoirloadedfalse
    \newif\ifisabntexloaded\isabntexloadedfalse
    \@ifclassloaded{memoir}{%
        \ismemoirloadedtrue%
    }{}
    \@ifclassloaded{abntex2}{%
        \isabntexloadedtrue%
    }{}
    \newcommand{\addGoToSummary}
    {%
        \@ifundefined{printparttitle}{\message{printparttitle patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
                    be applied because there is no printparttitle command available!^^J}}{%
            \let\oldAddGoToprintparttitle\printparttitle
            \xapptocmd{\printparttitle}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
        }
        \@ifundefined{Sectionformat}{\message{Sectionformat patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
                    be applied because there is no Sectionformat command available!^^J}}{%
            \let\oldAddGoToSectionformat\Sectionformat
            \xapptocmd{\Sectionformat}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
        }
        \ifismemoirloaded
            \ifisabntexloaded
                \let\oldAddGoToABNTEXchapterupperifneeded\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded
                \xapptocmd{\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
            \else
                \let\oldAddGoToprintchaptertitle\printchaptertitle
                \xapptocmd{\printchaptertitle}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
            \fi
        \else
            \@ifundefined{Chapterformat}{\message{Chapterformat patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
                        be applied because there is no Chapterformat command available!^^J}}{%
                \let\oldAddGoToChapterformat\Chapterformat
                \xapptocmd{\Chapterformat}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
            }
        \fi
    }
    \newcommand{\removeGoToSummary}
    {%
        \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToprintparttitle}{}{\let\printparttitle\oldAddGoToprintparttitle}
        \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToSectionformat}{}{\let\Sectionformat\oldAddGoToSectionformat}
        \ifismemoirloaded
            \ifisabntexloaded
                \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToABNTEXchapterupperifneeded}{}{\let\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded\oldAddGoToABNTEXchapterupperifneeded}
            \else
                \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToprintchaptertitle}{}{\let\printchaptertitle\oldAddGoToprintchaptertitle}
            \fi
        \else
            \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToChapterformat}{}{\let\Chapterformat\oldAddGoToChapterformat}
        \fi
    }
\makeatother
```

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % fix utf8 encoding problems
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{link_color}{RGB}{26,13,178}
\usepackage[backref,colorlinks,linkcolor=link_color]{hyperref}

\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,32,96}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\goToSummaryText}{{%
    \small\mdseries
    \hyperlink{summary}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{$\leftleftarrows$}}
    {$|$}
    \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{$\leftarrow$}}
}}
\makeatletter
    \newif\ifismemoirloaded\ismemoirloadedfalse
    \newif\ifisabntexloaded\isabntexloadedfalse
    \@ifclassloaded{memoir}{%
        \ismemoirloadedtrue%
    }{}
    \@ifclassloaded{abntex2}{%
        \isabntexloadedtrue%
    }{}
    \newcommand{\addGoToSummary}
    {%
        \@ifundefined{printparttitle}{\message{printparttitle patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
                    be applied because there is no printparttitle command available!^^J}}{%
            \let\oldAddGoToprintparttitle\printparttitle
            \xapptocmd{\printparttitle}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
        }
        \@ifundefined{Sectionformat}{\message{Sectionformat patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
                    be applied because there is no Sectionformat command available!^^J}}{%
            \let\oldAddGoToSectionformat\Sectionformat
            \xapptocmd{\Sectionformat}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
        }
        \ifismemoirloaded
            \ifisabntexloaded
                \let\oldAddGoToABNTEXchapterupperifneeded\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded
                \xapptocmd{\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
            \else
                \let\oldAddGoToprintchaptertitle\printchaptertitle
                \xapptocmd{\printchaptertitle}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
            \fi
        \else
            \@ifundefined{Chapterformat}{\message{Chapterformat patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
                        be applied because there is no Chapterformat command available!^^J}}{%
                \let\oldAddGoToChapterformat\Chapterformat
                \xapptocmd{\Chapterformat}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
            }
        \fi
    }
    \newcommand{\removeGoToSummary}
    {%
        \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToprintparttitle}{}{\let\printparttitle\oldAddGoToprintparttitle}
        \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToSectionformat}{}{\let\Sectionformat\oldAddGoToSectionformat}
        \ifismemoirloaded
            \ifisabntexloaded
                \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToABNTEXchapterupperifneeded}{}{\let\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded\oldAddGoToABNTEXchapterupperifneeded}
            \else
                \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToprintchaptertitle}{}{\let\printchaptertitle\oldAddGoToprintchaptertitle}
            \fi
        \else
            \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToChapterformat}{}{\let\Chapterformat\oldAddGoToChapterformat}
        \fi
    }
\makeatother
\let\oldAddGoTotableofcontents\tableofcontents
% Insert internal document link
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \hypertarget{summary}%
    \oldAddGoTotableofcontents%
}

\begin{document}

\addGoToSummary
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\section{Section One Four}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]