# Why abntex2 class is inserting a new line after the chapter title?

Tags: chapters, abnt

I am using this customization [How to automatically put a [Go To Summary] | [Go Back] on each section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367859/how-to-automatically-put-a-go-to-summary-go-back-on-each-section), but when I load it together with `abntex2` class, my go back buttons are put on the next line for the `\chapter{}` command. Everything works fine for `\section{}` and others:

[image]

If I remove the following code from the `abntex2` class, then, it is fixed:

https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/blob/15a981c300198ca59920eea17f02893490adf878/tex/latex/abntex2/abntex2.cls#L603-L614

```latex
  \def\printchaptertitle##1{%
    \chaptitlefont%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{abntex@innonumchapter}}{\centering\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded{##1}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{abntex@apendiceousecao}}{%
        \centering%
        \settowidth{\chapternamenumlength}{\printchaptername\printchapternum\afterchapternum}%
        \ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded{##1}%
      }{%
        \settowidth{\chapternamenumlength}{\printchaptername\printchapternum\afterchapternum}%
        \parbox[t]{\columnwidth-\chapternamenumlength}{\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded{##1}}}%
     }
  }
```

[image]

---

This is my minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass[
10pt,
a5paper
]{abntex2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,32,96}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\goToSummaryText}
{%
    \small\mdseries
    \hyperlink{summary}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{$\leftleftarrows$}}
    {$|$}
    \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{$\leftarrow$}}
}
\makeatletter
    \newif\ifismemoirloaded\ismemoirloadedfalse
    \@ifclassloaded{memoir}
    {%
        \ismemoirloadedtrue
    }{}
    \newcommand{\addGoToSummary}
    {%
        \renewcommand{\Sectionformat}[2]{##1 \protect\goToSummaryText}
        \ifismemoirloaded
            \let\oldprintchaptertitle\printchaptertitle
            \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\oldprintchaptertitle{##1} \protect\goToSummaryText}
        \else\fi
    }
    \newcommand{\removeGoToSummary}
    {%
        \renewcommand{\Sectionformat}[2]{##1}
        \ifismemoirloaded
            \let\printchaptertitle\oldprintchaptertitle
        \else\fi
    }
\makeatother
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}
{%
    \hypertarget{summary}%
    \oldtableofcontents%
}

\begin{document}
    \addGoToSummary
    \chapter{Section contents}
    thing2.
\end{document}
```

How can I patch `abntex2` class or my command to fix this issue?

References:

1. [What is the equivalent to `\Sectionformat` on memoir class for `\Chapterformat`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399635/what-is-the-equivalent-to-sectionformat-on-memoir-class-for-chapterformat)
2. [How can the go to summary be fixed so the \section[Some]{Some more} does not throw all these errors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388045/how-can-the-go-to-summary-be-fixed-so-the-sectionsomesome-more)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by checking whether the `abntex2` is loaded and patching directly `\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded`.

If someone knows a better or more general answer, please share it!

```latex
\documentclass[
10pt,
a5paper
]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,32,96}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\goToSummaryText}{{%
    \small\mdseries
    \hyperlink{summary}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{$\leftleftarrows$}}
    {$|$}
    \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{$\leftarrow$}}
}}
\makeatletter
    \newif\ifismemoirloaded\ismemoirloadedfalse
    \newif\ifisabntexloaded\isabntexloadedfalse
    \@ifclassloaded{memoir}{%
        \ismemoirloadedtrue%
    }{}
    \@ifclassloaded{abntex2}{%
        \isabntexloadedtrue%
    }{}
    \newcommand{\addGoToSummary}
    {%
        \@ifundefined{printparttitle}{\message{printparttitle patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
                    be applied because there is no printparttitle command available!^^J}}{%
            \let\oldAddGoToprintparttitle\printparttitle
            \xapptocmd{\printparttitle}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
        }
        \@ifundefined{Sectionformat}{\message{Sectionformat patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
                    be applied because there is no Sectionformat command available!^^J}}{%
            \let\oldAddGoToSectionformat\Sectionformat
            \xapptocmd{\Sectionformat}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
        }
        \ifismemoirloaded
            \ifisabntexloaded
                \let\oldAddGoToABNTEXchapterupperifneeded\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded
                \xapptocmd{\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
            \else
                \let\oldAddGoToprintchaptertitle\printchaptertitle
                \xapptocmd{\printchaptertitle}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
            \fi
        \else
            \@ifundefined{Chapterformat}{\message{Chapterformat patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
                        be applied because there is no Chapterformat command available!^^J}}{%
                \let\oldAddGoToChapterformat\Chapterformat
                \xapptocmd{\Chapterformat}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
            }
        \fi
    }
    \newcommand{\removeGoToSummary}
    {%
        \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToprintparttitle}{}{\let\printparttitle\oldAddGoToprintparttitle}
        \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToSectionformat}{}{\let\Sectionformat\oldAddGoToSectionformat}
        \ifismemoirloaded
            \ifisabntexloaded
                \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToABNTEXchapterupperifneeded}{}{\let\ABNTEXchapterupperifneeded\oldAddGoToABNTEXchapterupperifneeded}
            \else
                \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToprintchaptertitle}{}{\let\printchaptertitle\oldAddGoToprintchaptertitle}
            \fi
        \else
            \@ifundefined{oldAddGoToChapterformat}{}{\let\Chapterformat\oldAddGoToChapterformat}
        \fi
    }
\makeatother
\let\oldAddGoTotableofcontents\tableofcontents
% Insert internal document link
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \hypertarget{summary}%
    \oldAddGoTotableofcontents%
}

\begin{document}
    \addGoToSummary
    \part{My}
    \chapter{Chapter title}
    thing1.
    \removeGoToSummary
    \section{Section title}
    thing2.
    \addGoToSummary
    \section{Section title}
    thing3.
\end{document}
```

References:

1. [Why abntex2 class is inserting a new line after the chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485834/why-abntex2-class-is-inserting-a-new-line-after-the-chapter-title)
2. [How to automatically put a [Go To Summary] | [Go Back] on each section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367859/how-to-automatically-put-a-go-to-summary-go-back-on-each-section)
3. [How can the go to summary be fixed so the \section[Some]{Some more} does not throw all these errors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388045/how-can-the-go-to-summary-be-fixed-so-the-sectionsomesome-more)
4. [What is the equivalent to `\Sectionformat` on memoir class for `\Chapterformat`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399635/what-is-the-equivalent-to-sectionformat-on-memoir-class-for-chapterformat)
5. [Why xapptocmd is reducing the vertical space between \partname and \parttile?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485857/why-xapptocmd-is-reducing-the-vertical-space-between-partname-and-parttile)