# Why xapptocmd is reducing the vertical space between \partname and \parttile?

Tags: spacing, memoir, line-spacing, xpatch

Running this example:

```latex
\documentclass[
10pt,
a5paper
]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,32,96}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\goToSummaryText}{%
    \small\mdseries
    \hyperlink{summary}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{$\leftleftarrows$}}
    {$|$}
    \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{$\leftarrow$}}
}
\makeatletter
    \newif\ifismemoirloaded\ismemoirloadedfalse
    \newif\ifisabntexloaded\isabntexloadedfalse
    \@ifclassloaded{memoir}{%
        \ismemoirloadedtrue%
    }{}
    \@ifclassloaded{abntex2}{%
        \isabntexloadedtrue%
    }{}
    \newcommand{\addGoToSummary}
    {%
        \@ifundefined{printpartnum}{\message{printpartnum patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
            be applied because there is no printpartnum command available!^^J}}{%
            \let\oldAddGoToprintpartnum\printpartnum
            \xapptocmd{\printpartnum}{~\protect\goToSummaryText}{}{}
        }
    }
\makeatother

\let\oldAddGoTotableofcontents\tableofcontents
% Insert internal document link
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \hypertarget{summary}%
    \oldAddGoTotableofcontents%
}

\begin{document}
    \addGoToSummary
    \part{My}
\end{document}
```

We get this PDF:

[image]

If if I change `\printpartnum` to `\printparttitle`, the vertical spacing between the `\printpartname` and `\printparttitle` is reduced:

[image]

How can I patch the `\printpartname` while keeping the original spacing between `\printpartname` and `\printparttitle`?

Looking at the memoir class code for the `\part` command, I cannot understand why the spacing is breaking:

```latex
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \parskip\z@
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
     \printpartname \partnamenum \printpartnum
     \midpartskip
   \fi
   \printparttitle{#2}\par}%
  \@endpart}
```

Related questions:

1. [Why abntex2 class is inserting a new line after the chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485834/why-abntex2-class-is-inserting-a-new-line-after-the-chapter-title)
2. [How to automatically put a [Go To Summary] | [Go Back] on each section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367859/how-to-automatically-put-a-go-to-summary-go-back-on-each-section)
3. [How can the go to summary be fixed so the \section[Some]{Some more} does not throw all these errors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388045/how-can-the-go-to-summary-be-fixed-so-the-sectionsomesome-more)
4. [What is the equivalent to `\Sectionformat` on memoir class for `\Chapterformat`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399635/what-is-the-equivalent-to-sectionformat-on-memoir-class-for-chapterformat)

---

## Update

I managed to fix it with this hack, but still not working correctly.

I would prefer a generic solution than this, if this is an actual solution because if someone changes the `\midpartskip` to something else as `50pt`, their value would be overridden by `30pt` set here:

```
    \newif\ifismemoirloaded\ismemoirloadedfalse
    \@ifclassloaded{memoir}{%
        \ismemoirloadedtrue%
    }{}
    \newcommand{\addGoToSummary}
    {%
        \@ifundefined{printparttitle}{\message{printparttitle patch for addGoToSummary could NOT
            be applied because there is no printparttitle command available!^^J}}{%
            \let\oldAddGoToprintparttitle\printparttitle
            \let\oldAddGoToprintpartnum\printpartnum
            \xapptocmd{\printpartnum}{%
                \let\oldAddGoTomidpartskip\midpartskip%
                \renewcommand{\midpartskip}{\par\vskip 30pt}%
            }{}{}
            \xapptocmd{\printparttitle}{%
                \let\midpartskip\oldAddGoTomidpartskip%
                ~\protect\goToSummaryText%
            }{}{}
        }
    }
    \newcommand{\removeGoToSummary}
    {%
        \@ifundefined{printparttitle}{\message{printparttitle patch for removeGoToSummary could NOT
            be applied because there is no printparttitle command available!^^J}}{%
            \let\printparttitle\oldAddGoToprintparttitle
            \let\printpartnum\oldAddGoToprintpartnum
        }
    }
```

<s>This other thing also a similar effect, but the distance did not get 100% equal. The distance was a little bigger than `30pt`. I added `\protect` to `\midpartskip` and set `\midpartskip` back on the other command.</s>

```
            \let\oldAddGoToprintparttitle\printparttitle
            \let\oldAddGoToprintpartnum\printpartnum
            \xapptocmd{\printpartnum}{%
                \let\oldAddGoTomidpartskip\protect\midpartskip%
            }{}{}
            \xapptocmd{\printparttitle}{%
                \let\midpartskip\oldAddGoTomidpartskip%
                ~\protect\goToSummaryText%
            }{}{}
```

Correction, this did not work at all. When I tried to set:

```latex
\begin{document}
    \addGoToSummary
    \setlength\midchapskip{50pt}
    \part{My}
\end{document}
```

I was completely ignored and the distance still about `32pt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a group:

```
\newcommand{\goToSummaryText}{{% group here
    \small\mdseries
    \hyperlink{summary}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{$\leftleftarrows$}}
    {$|$}
    \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\textcolor{ultramarine}{$\leftarrow$}}%
}}
```

with the original definition the `\small` was affecting the baselineskip so you were getting `\lineskip` spacing.